# Rectangle Stroke looks weird on Firemonkey Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have created a `Multi device` application on my `Delphi 10.2 Tokyo` and dropped a `TRectangle` with these properties

```
  object Rectangle1: TRectangle
    Fill.Kind = None
    Position.X = 56.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 104.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 225.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 273.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Stroke.Color = claChartreuse
    Stroke.Thickness = 30.000000000000000000
  end
```

well in Windows it looks normal where in android it looks weird

[image] 
[image]
so how can i fix this issue .
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the current values of `Stroke.Cap`, `Stroke.Join`, and `Stroke.Kind`?

Comment: the defaults ones `flat` `miter` `solid`

Comment: Same here. My Android environment isn't working properly at the moment, but that is very strange behavior. Which version of Delphi in particular?

Comment: Delphi 10.2 Tokyo

Comment: Possibly related to this issue: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13042 and https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15649

Comment: the example provided shows how to use native draw to draw rectangles at run time but I wanted if there is a way to fix the issuse using TRectangle Control

Answer (score 1):

Delphi basic Trectangle Use openGL to draw on the screen. well i see sometime very strange think with openGL geometrie on some devices (like line draw on the bottom of the screen are more fat that the same line draw on the top of the screen). it's depend of the device of course, and the quality of the device. maybe what you see is also part of this strange behavior. try to change the Form.quality params to see if it's can help, and also the Stroke.Cap and Stroke.Join.

anyway what i can gave you as a solution, is to not use Trectangle (that by the way is very slow to draw with round corner) but instead use TalRectangle from [Alcinoe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/alcinoe/)

NOTE: you must also know that Tokyo must be avoid for any android developpement and you must use instead Berlin

Comment: I have already tampered with cap and join and quality too but it stills the same

Comment: try fastly with TALRectangle in Alcinoe and say me it's it's change something ...