# HTML Component library ThtPanel incorrectly renders HTML on Android

Tags: delphi, svg, firemonkey

I'm using the `ThtPanel` component from the HTML Component library (version 4.5) to create icons in my application.

On Windows everything looks great, but on Android the same icons are rendered incorrectly.

For example if I set the `HTML` property of the `ThtPanel` to something like this:

```
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:30;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

The output on Windows is this:

[image: 1]

But on Android it looks like this:

[image: 2]

This problem makes all my icons on Android look low quality. I tried messing with the properties on the `ThtPanel`, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You will need to send this to the developer of the HTML Components, or deep dive into the source yourself.  It looks to me as though the Android and Windows versions are treating the line endings differently.  Most drawing routines will allow the caller to provide different line endings and different ones are being chosen, either explicitly or because the default on the two platforms are different.  If you can locate the routine that is drawing the rect in your svg you can investigate further.

Comment: Talked with the developer of HTML Components. It's a bug, but a bug in fmx. Turns out the problem is the same as this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/46677355/9098350. The developer provided me with a temporary fix which changes how html components draws rectangles.

Comment: Their fix was basically to create the path directly instead of letting the DrawRect function of the canvas draw the path.

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to reproduce this I'm pretty sure this is just a misunderstanding and happens often with markup, especially in the context of web documents: if you don't define it then you cannot have expectations.

While the average experience must have reached you that different web browsers slightly differ in what and how they render websites, the culprit is that they have different engines to interpret your markup and then to render the optics out of it. However, it is quickly forgotten that web browsers come with configurations and these can change - either on purpose (every font by default should be a serif) or with slightly unexpected results (because websites always expect that the default font is a sans-serif).

Long story short: your SVG rectangle nowhere defines how edges at the end of strokes should be drawn. As per [SVG 13.5.4. Drawing caps at the ends of strokes: the ‘stroke-linecap’ property](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#LineCaps) you should define

```css
stroke-linecap: square
```

...while you already defined [`stroke`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#SpecifyingStrokePaint) and [`stroke-width`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeWidth).

Try that first and load it in different browsers/engines - I'm pretty sure it makes a difference. Note: *Windows* is neither a web browser, nor a rendering engine. And so is *Android*. They can can different web browsers/engines.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and insights. Haven't gotten this to work, but I think this answer is on the right track. Will experiment further.